# C# open source NMEA parser

Tags: c#, nmea

Am looking for C# open source NMEA parser.

Comment: I know that this is really really old, but I just started building one myself here
https://github.com/DevsAnon/NmeaParser

it will be only a parser compared to other libraries that include connections etc, so no overhead. And with full support of .net standard.
it will be a nuget package and released soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I'm not familiar with it myself, but some quick searches show one on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/NMEAtoOSG.aspx), which links to 2 other such, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/WritingGPSApplications1.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/WritingGPSApplications2.aspx). Any of those help?

Answer (score 5):

check out [sharpGPS](http://www.codeplex.com/SharpGPS) . there are several other gps and nmea related projects o codeplex too

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, it's not hard (10-40 LOC) to parse the basic ones your self. If you find you need to do this, [here](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm) is a link with some useful info.

Answer (score 1):

One more (support several devices)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/279647/NMEA-sentence-parser-builder